# setLineBackground for GridLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, plugins, background, swt

I want to create a zebra background for an Eclipse plug-in SWT GUI.
one line gray, one line white, one line gray and so on.
So I want to set the background for every line [like this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/StyledTextsetlinebackground.htm).

But I don't want to use StyledText and when I set the background on each component on the line, gaps appear. An label behind the components isn't an option, because SWT don't know depth.

So how do I change the background color of a whole line in a GridLayout?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The gaps are due to the margin/spacing of the `GridLayout`, just set [`GridLayout.marginHeight`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridLayout.html#marginHeight) and [`GridLayout.verticalSpacing`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridLayout.html#verticalSpacing) to `0`

Comment: @Baz Still white spacing showing

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? And possibly post your code, i.e. an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
private static final Color[] colors = new Color[2];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,  false));

    Composite content = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    content.setLayout(layout);
    content.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    colors[0] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY);
    colors[1] = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        createPart(content, i);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createPart(Composite parent, int i)
{
    Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    comp.setLayout(layout);
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    comp.setBackground(colors[i % 2]);

    Label left = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    left.setText("Left");
    left.setBackground(colors[i % 2]);
    Label right = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    right.setText("Right");
    right.setBackground(colors[i % 2]);
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works almost for me. But still the margin doesn't work fine for me. [link](http://i.tinyuploads.com/2X7EYG.jpg)

Comment: @Lutske Which OS are you using? Did you change the code I provided?

Comment: Windows, I changed the shell into the composite. Because I make an Eclipse plug-in so I don't use a shell but a composite. So on the CreatePart method I give the composite on the parameters and don't make an new composite.

Comment: @Lutske Update the code to use a `Composite` instead. Still works. Can't test it in a plugin, since I don't have working code for it just now.

Comment: I think it is a bug in my code somewhere else. So thank you very much. I accept this answer.

Comment: with labels it's no problem, but with other components like textfields, comboboxes and so on, the background stop when the element stops.

Comment: @Lutske Tried my code with `Text`s instead of `Label`s (even with `Combo`s), still works.

Comment: probably because I use the method now to return the color, but the most important part of the method is the new composite. Thanks:)